# Laravel make:auth — How do I send 2 queries from 1 form? e.g: email to one table & username to another table

Tags: mysql, laravel

Basically, I want 2 tables, one named accounts and the other named characters.
So for example, let me create some fictional data to make this easier.

(account_id auto increments)
The person would fill this registration form:

```
Account Name: Johnny
Character Name: John_Doe
Email: john_doe@gmail.com
Password: ********
Confirm Password: ********
```

So what I wanted to do is:
* Send 'account_id' to both tables(accounts & characters
* Send 'account name', 'email', password' to accounts
* Send 'character_name' to characters

I'm new to Laravel so I don't really know where to start, does this have anything to do with it?
/database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('account_name');
        $table->string('character_name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
    });
}
```

Best case scenario would be tables looking like this.

```
accounts [  
    'account_id' => 1  
    'username' => Johnny  
    'email' => john_doe@gmail.com  
    'password' => ********  
]  

characters [  
    'account_id' => 1  
    'character_name' => John_Doe  
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation on [eloquent models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#defining-models) and `[database migrations][2]`.

The quick-n-dirty guide is:

`$ php artisan make:migrate create_characters_table`

Then in database\migrations\xxxxxxxxx_create_characters_table.php...

```
    $table->bigInteger('account_id')->unsigned(); // Laravel's default primary keys are unsigned big integers. So foreign keys must have the same datatype.
    $table->string('character_name');
```

Then in the controller method it's as simple as:

```php
use App\Character;

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $newCharacter = Character::create([
        'account_id' => $request->input('account_id'),
        'character_name' => $request->input('character_name')
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is this controller method...?

Comment: I highly recommend you just disregard everything I said and go to Laracasts and start watching [Laravel From Scratch](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2018).